# Visual Code/WebStorm behave differently when indenting multiline assignment operator

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, code-formatting

I have the following lines of code:

```js
const [
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
] = [
    ...someArray,
    ...someOtherArray,
];
```

WebStorm formats these lines as shown above, but Visual Studio Code formats them as follows:

```js
const [
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
] = [
        ...someArray,
        ...someOtherArray,
    ];
```

None of them have code formatting plugins - just the default packages that they come with. I don't really have a preference towards any of the 2 ways, but I want a consistent behavior between the two editors and I can't find the setting which influences the indent decision in this case. I've spent hours scrolling through every possible code formatting option in both editors, but the indent decision seems to come out of thin air. Does anyone know where or how can I modify it?

It's worth mentioning that if the code looks like this:

```js
const [a, b, c, d] = [
    ...someArray,
    ...someOtherArray,
];
```

then both editors format it as above. The issue seems to be when the `=` operator is on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to change the indentation in vscode and webstorm settings to the same value. To use spaces or tab and 2 or 4 indentation size.

Comment: They are both configured to have 4 spaces for indenting. That shouldn't be the issue, especially since in the last scenario given in the question both IDEs behave the same.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `printWidth`? It might shorter in vscode than webstorm.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `printWidth`. Is it a setting option? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, it's a setting in vscode. It might be named something else in webstorm. It's the code line limit. I can't really think of anything else since this is pretty strange behaviour and is just the default way of formatting for both editors. 

The best solution would be to download the prettier plugin and configure it with the same setting for both editors.